# Auto-touch/upload wsgi file with pycharm

Tags: pycharm, wsgi, remote-server

I am developing a wsgi application using PyCharm IDE and deploying my changes automatically to remote server, but I still need to touch wsgi file for the changes to take effect.

Is there a way to touch/upload wsgi file automatically if I change another file with PyCharm?
(This was very trivial with Sublime Text 2)

Comment: I would love this feature too. I created a feature request with Jetbrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-26550